# To fetch embedded code from Email subject

Tags: c#

There will be code which will be anywhere in the Email subject and starts with any of the following 2 characters.

IC*, IB*, IJ*, CZ*, TC*

**I need help to find this code.**

Example Email subject :

- Barcode IC129052 [TEST] PLEASE PROVIDE THE PAN DETAILS TO UPDATE.
- IJ574299 Please DISCARD (without word Barcode)
- This Email is to complete payment for TC20200810007.

Conditions on code :

- Code will start with 2 alphabet and rest will be numeric only, ranging from 4 to 11 digits.
- There can be multiple code in the same subject. (Example : Complete payment for
- IJ202021 IJ20200900014). If multiple, need to fetch all code.
  Maximum of 4 barcodes will only be there in subject.

**What I tried :**

Earlier there was a standard format in the subject line, In which “CODENUM” word was prefixed before actual code. I used to look for “CODENUM”  and fetch the all characters before space.(Example :  CODENUM IC129052 [TEST] PLEASE PROVIDE THE PAN DETAILS TO UPDATE.)

It was simple substring logic

```
EmailSubject =  //Has Email subject 

Regex tempRegex = new Regex(@"\(([^\)]+)\)");

EmailSubject = EmailSubject.Replace(".EML","");
EmailSubject = EmailSubject.Replace(".MSG","");
EmailSubject = EmailSubject.Substring(EmailSubject.LastIndexOf("CODENUM ")+11);
EmailSubject = EmailSubject.Replace(" ","");
EmailSubject = EmailSubject.Replace("-","");
EmailSubject = EmailSubject.Replace("_","");
EmailSubject = tempRegex.Replace(EmailSubject,"" );                                
                                           
int length = EmailSubject.Length;                            
                                                                                      
 if(length > 4)
   {
     //SAVE Value                                        

    }
```

But with this new requirement I need help to determine this, Since I a very new to C#, please help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
string subject = "Complete payment for IJ202021 TC20200900014 Some text Some Tex bla IB24354235235 Some more text CZ25235645xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string pattern = @"[A-Z]{2}\d+";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
var matches = reg.Matches(subject);
foreach (var mt in matches)
{
    if (mt.ToString().Length > 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mt.ToString());
        // Save...
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
IJ202021
TC20200900014
IB24354235235
CZ25235645